# Como fazer um algoritmo guloso para resolver o problema da mochila em java

Tags: java

Lembrando que não estou conseguindo fazer o calculo para resolver esse problema

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-problem/ Dá uma olhada aí

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa se juntar a uma equipe de pesquisa de alguma faculdade de projeção mundial - de preferência as mais voltadas a tecnologia, como o a Caltech ou o MIT. Passe anos estudando, lidere uma equipe multidisciplinar, e talvez desenvolvendo algum hardware novo (ou usando processadores quânticos) você consiga. O que eu falei até agora pode parecer sarcasmo, mas eu juro que não é. Estou falando sério.

O [problema da mochila](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila) é um problema [NP-completo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completo). Não vou entrar nos mínimos detalhes técnicos, mas basta saber por enquanto que, para todos os fins práticos, nenhum desses problemas jamais foi resolvido a contento com um algoritmo computável.

Se você conseguir resolver o problema da mochila, poderá descobrir finalmente se P != NP. Fica a dica, [isso vale um prêmio milhão de dólares do Clay Mathematics Institute](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem).